# DefaultHttpClient, Certificates, Https: Access diened

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpsurlconnection, sslsocketfactory

I have to connect to a secured https url and I followed these steps:

1. Create the `HttpClient` :

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);

registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
registry.register(new Scheme("http", socketFactory, 80));
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());  
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

2. I create a `HttpPost`:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("");
post.setHeader("Content-Type",  "application/json");
post.setHeader("TOKEN", token);
post.setHeader("Accept", "*/*");
HttpEntity e = new StringEntity(json.toString());
post.setEntity(e);
```

3. I executed the request:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

The response shows that **access is denied**.

Can somebody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes, allowing all hosts is not enough. It could be that the other end is requesting a Client Certificate and you're not providing one.

Comment: "Access Denied" is usually a message from the server indicating that your request misses or contains wrong authentication data like username/password or an authentication token. If the data is correct the used account may be does not have the permission to execute the function you want to use.